# Python graph x axis reversed, how to show 0 to n?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Hello dear developers,

I have a problem in Python. It shows me this weird visualization of the x-axis here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQJ90.png

But as you will obviously understand I want the classic style, where it begins with 0 and the bar reaches out to the value instead of remaining empty at the maximum.

What I have are 2 arrays. The first array contains the y-labels and the other one contains the values.

```
currentLabels = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8', 'test9', 'test10']
currentCount = ['20', '14', '9', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,100))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,1)
ax.barh(y=currentLabels, width=currentCount)

[... some more code that don't solve the problem when getting commented ...]

plt.show()
```

I don't understand where the problem is... I've already tried `ax.invert_xaxis()` but it ended up moving the chart lines to the right:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iKS5.png

I would be very thankful if someone would provide me a solution out of this, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you attach some of your data?

Comment: hi, which data do you mean ? I already attached the label and count-data in the picture links

Comment: It would help if we could see the data vectors you'd like to plot, so that we could try and reproduce the problem

Comment: oh of course I'll add it to the question thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs to `barh()` are the labels and the widths, which should be numbers. Change `currentCount` to:

```
currentCount = [20, 14, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To get:

[image]